Am I misunderstanding how `std::views::cartesian_product` is supposed to work?
Edit: see also a connected question.

I have tested the following program on godbolt:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{"\x{01}\x{02}\x{03}\x{04}"};

    auto view = std::views::istream<char>(iss) | std::views::chunk(2) |
                std::views::transform([](auto t) {
                    return std::ranges::fold_left(t, 0, std::plus{});
                });

    for (const auto& p :
         std::views::cartesian_product(view, std::views::iota(0, 3))) {
        const auto [s, i] = p;
        std::cout << s << ", " << i << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

The result with both GCC and clang is:
3, 0
0, 1
0, 2
7, 0
0, 1
0, 2

Since the first std::views::cartesian_product argument is supposed to be only passed through a single time, shouldn't it rather be the following?
3, 0
3, 1
3, 2
7, 0
7, 1
7, 2


I saw a relevant question in a comment that then was removed: dereferencing the  iterator returned by view.begin() three times gives 3, 0, 0, which should be the root cause.

Removing chunk and transform show that input_range is correctly handled Demo

@Jarod42, yes. And switching to a forward range shows that chunk and transform, on their own, are not either the problem. On the other hand, as you in fact very early hinted at, input_range + chunk + transform can very easily be problematic. The approved answer says it all.

The problem here is the transform actually.
There are two facts that we're running afoul of:

Input ranges can only be traversed one single time. Doing so consumes them.
transform(f) must be equality-preserving. That is, the function, f, that you are providing must return the same answer given the same input.

When you're doing fold_left in the transform, the argument there (t) is an input range (the originating istream<char> is an input range, and then chunk-ing it gives you an input range of input ranges). fold_left has to traverse that range, which consumes it. But you can only do that one single time. The second time you do it, there's nothing left to traverse, so you have en empty range.
Put differently, you're violating the expectation of iterators, which is:
auto it = /* some iterator */;
auto v1 = *it;
auto v2 = *it;
assert(v1 == v2);

By providing a callable which consumes its input, it's preventing this iterator dereference from producing the same value every time. And that's the behavior you see, you get the expected answer the first time (3 and then 7) but then garbage every other time (0 because that's what your fold gives on an empty range).

There are two ways to fix this.
One is to make the range non-input, for instance by first consuming the whole views::istream<char> into a vector<char> and then doing the chunk | transform(fold) on the resulting vector. Now our chunks aren't input-only, so the fold can give the same answer every time.
The other is to "fix" the result of the transform in the literal sense by avoiding recalculating it. range-v3 has an adaptor for this (cache1) and there is one proposed for standardization called cache_last P3138:
auto view = views::istream<char>(iss)
          | views::chunk(2)
          | views::transform([](auto t) {
              return ranges::fold_left(t, 0, plus{});
            })
          | views::cache_last // <== add me
          ;   

cache_last simply caches the last value, ensuring that *it repeatedly always produces the same thing since we never go back to the underlying iterator. Since we're only calling fold exactly one time, we don't run into the input issue.
I'm not sure if there's really a good way of diagnosing such mis-uses.

"Fixing" the range is in my case not an option, since the point of the concerned code is to do unit testing in the input range case. In fact, then, those unit tests have just showed that my implementation is broken for input ranges. So cache_last is not only for performance then. Very interesting, thanks.

Funny stuff, thank you. During my research on this I was step away from this answer, but made one wrong step, since lacked the way to trace/debug the states of the input ranges. Two questions here: is there a way to debug/trace this so that effect is visible in debugger and how to avoid such issues (easy to get such problem again and fixes help only for fixing, but not for catching in real large code)?

With the second "fix", my program is still ill-formed according to the standard, right? In that case, it does not sound like an acceptable solution to me.

Rolling my own instead of insisting on trying to compose existing range adaptors is also a solution. I was hoping it would not be necessary, but I do want to provide support for input ranges. AND to preserve forward ranges, sized ranges, etc. The latter has also been an issue with some other combinations.

Interesting... then Is it possible to prevent a view being consumed?

@LouisGo, see related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79069912/stdviewschunk-stdviewstransform-inputs-ranges-and-ill-formedness.

@nilo Technically you're still violating the requirements on transform because the callable still isn't a regular invocable. But that's unobservable, since you're effectively regularizing it with cache_last so it's fine.

So an unobservable ill-formedness is fine? I did learn something today. Thanks.

@nilo The reason that transform has the requirement on regular_invocable is that this is the expectation on iterators - *it produces the same thing if you call it multiple times. If you wrap it in cache_last, *it will produce the same thing if you call it multiple times. Does it really matter how we got there? If it really bothers you, you can write a cache_transform adapter that basically combines transform(f) | cache_last, which is pretty easy because it's only input so you don't need to worry about most of the API.

Actually, I had implicitly shifted to another requirement that would be broken: "requiring the invoke expression to [...] not modify [...] the arguments". But in this case, is the function not passed a view by value? So formally, while it has side-effects through the view, it cannot possibly be modifying it? So you are really only talking about equality-preservation? Then I agree with the non-observability argument.

This is not related to std::views::cartesian_product, which works correctly. This is related to your std::istringstream iss or (as stated in comments) to its usage in the std::views::istream<char>(iss).
Replace it with vector and everything would work as expected:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::vector<int> iss{ 1, 2, 3, 4};

    auto view = iss | std::views::chunk(2) |
        std::views::transform([](auto t) {
        return std::ranges::fold_left(t, 0, std::plus{});
            });

    for (const auto& p :
        std::views::cartesian_product(view, std::views::iota(0, 3))) {
        const auto [s, i] = p;
        std::cout << s << ", " << i << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

with the results:
3, 0
3, 1
3, 2
7, 0
7, 1
7, 2

Demo.
So, this answers to your question on how std::views::cartesian_product is supposed to work and narrows your way to look for issue with std::istringstream and, possibly, its view.
Solution and conclusions
While everything is covered in detail in the answer above from Barry, I’d like to provide my takeaways here, since the problem is funny and worth lessons learned. I wouldn’t repeat what is said in the Barry’s answer, but rather would provide my view for the problem (although these are just different faces of the same thing). Just is case it would help someone in similar research cases and as a keepsake knot for me.
When I work with views, I assume that they should provide some “static” representation of underlying data and this assumption is correct. With the same input data, the view should return the same result.
The difference comes when we consider the “staticness”. When we wrap up the data into a stream, data still being static is now accessed dynamically though the stream view which is not static from the reading perspective and fold_left’s usage effect highlights this fact. Now this is not a view actually, but a flow and now we must be very careful with views’ use cases, since for most of them we assume and anticipate “staticness” from all perspectives. We expect to have views, not flows.
With all the mentioned above, I would personally think twice before using streams with views, since although this is still valid and helpful, this is very risky for the common views’ mindset.
Lessons learned
I was a step away from the solution, found by Barry, but I suspected the std::views::istream and focus on it allowed me to stuck on the "The iterator type of basic_istream_view is move-only: it does not meet the LegacyIterator requirements" and decide that this explanation covers the issue.
I saw with simple debugging code that the view is consumed, but I stopped with my hypothesis. "Divide et impera”. I had to divide the view to parts and study each of them to finally pinpoint the root case. This wasn’t done in this case because of “good enough” result balance which failed me this time.

I voted this up although it only really gives an example of std::views::cartesian_product working as expected when the first argument is a std::ranges::random_access_range, which is a lot more than what std::views::cartesian_product is supposed to require (std::ranges::input_range according the specification).

@nilo, yes I understand it. I am just narrowing the search area. The initial question is about std::views::cartesian_product. It seems the focus must be shifted on how std::views::cartesian_product works with std::ranges::input_range. Additional question is how std::istringstream should be treated in range types terms and what in this terms we get as the view, although it seems to be working fine. So, at the moment I am questioning if std::istringstream could be used safely to get std::ranges::input_range.

I guess the answer is "cartesian_product should require forward_range on all inputs". This is a std defect. Just imagine how would it be possible? Input iterators and ranges are single pass, and Cartesian product is inherently multipass. If cache_latest was available, it's result must have at least been forward_range.

@Red.Wave, are you referring to https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2024/p3138r0.html? But that's a performance optimization, right? I'm not sure why you say "cartesian_product should require forward_range on all inputs". Shouldn't we be able to dereference the first view's iterator multiple times and expect the same result every time?

@nilo, I've updated the answer. Please let me know if it still needs further details or clarifications.

@DamirTenishev, what is your source for claiming the non-input_range part? GCC and Clang disagree: https://godbolt.org/z/cGKfabEfn. The problem seems to be that and transform is invoked multiple times but gets an empty view from the second time.

The stuff in the "update" is wrong - basic_istream_view is definitely an input_range.

@Barry, removed the "Update" section, but the question is still on the table, what makes you think that basic_istream_view is definitely an input_range? Any references to standard or any other source?

basic_istream_view is a view, hence a range, and its iterator is an input_iterator. That combination is the definition of an input_range.

@nilo, what about the "The iterator type of basic_istream_view is move-only: it does not meet the LegacyIterator requirements" from the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/basic_istream_view?

LegacyIterator has no relevance to input_range.

@nilo, yes but I take the cach_last argument back. The very definition of input_range and input_iterator implies that only the first pass over the iterator/range is valid; the second and forth passes are UB. Thus, I am astonished that cartesian_product accepts an input_range as its first input. This looks like a std defect. OTOH zip cannot take any input_range, which is excessively restrictive. The correct behavior would be that cartesian_product takes only foward_range, while zip is allowed to handle input_range.

@Red.Wave, cartesian_product does not need to pass through its first argument more than once. The problem here is dereferencing multiple times, not passing through multiple times. Also, views::zip is specified for input_range. And works in practice with such ranges: https://godbolt.org/z/qcGMfnxbv.

@nilo, again, zip is my fault. The dereferencing problem is exactly the specification of input_range. Single pass means single iteration, and dereferencing. cartesian_product passes through all elements multiple times. Maybe we need another category in between input_range and forward_range. One that cach_lastfits in. That would solve many problems including famous drop last problem withviews::istream. Or maybe require every input_range` to internally cach last value.

@Red.Wave, what is your source for multiple dereferencing of input_range iterator being  illegal?

@Red.Wave Cartesian product only has to pass through its first range one time, so there is no reason (other than symmetry I guess) to require the first range to be forward.

@Barry , where's the root cause of the problem? I am now thinking that input_range is underspecified. Or do we need a stable_input_range concept? One with guaranteed dereference on none-end iterators.

@Red.Wave The root cause of what problem? I don't know what you're talking about.

@Red.Wave, when I said "The problem here is dereferencing multiple times" you answered "The dereferencing problem is exactly the specification of input_range". But according to my understanding, there is not limit on how many times a C++ program is allowed to dereference an iterator, regardless of iterator type. When it comes to the root-cause of the dereferencing issue in my case, I encourage you to read the accepted answer, which explain exactly that.

@nilo input_range is by definition a range represented by input_iterators. The later term is at least 3 decades old and its definition implies single dereferencing via single-pass iteration constraints.

@Red.Wave, which paragraph in the C++ standard are you referring to?

@Red.Wave, the reason I'm asking is that I believe we have established that both GCC and Clang do dereference input_iterators multiple times so I cannot see any other next step than referring to the letter of the standard.

@nilo that's news. AFAIK input_iterator has never guaranteed that kind of behavior.

@Red.Wave, N4950, working draft, 25.3.4.9 Concept input_iterator:  "The input_iterator concept defines requirements for a type whose referenced values can be read (from the requirement for indirectly_readable (25.3.4.2)) and which can be both pre- and post-incremented."

25.3.4.2 Concept indirectly_readable: "Types that are indirectly readable by applying operator* model the indirectly_readable concept, including pointers, smart pointers, and iterators. [...] Given a value i of type I, I models indirectly_readable only if the expression *i is equality-preserving."

It mentions *i is equality-preserving, which only matters if dereferencing is called several times. That's common for all iterators, but I see no special mention for input_iterators that would prevent multi dereferencing. Basically the concept is that you can read it and only go forward, not much more. Saying "you can read it, but only once", would seem really strange to me. What practical advantage would that have?

Then try std::istream_iterator. It is supposedly the prime instance of input_iterator.

@Red.Wave: what? We were discussing your claim that input_iterator would not support multi-dereferencing, and can find no trace of that in the standard. For me that ends that discussion. The OP question has an accepted answer and all is fine.
