std::views::chunk, std::views::transform, inputs ranges, and ill-formedness
Consider program 1:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{"\x{01}\x{02}\x{03}\x{04}"};

    auto view = std::views::istream<char>(iss) | std::views::chunk(2) |
                std::views::transform([](auto chunk) {
                    return std::ranges::fold_left(chunk, 0, std::plus{});
                });

    static_assert(
        std::ranges::input_range<decltype(std::views::istream<char>(iss))>);
    static_assert(not std::ranges::forward_range<
                  decltype(std::views::istream<char>(iss))>);

    for (const auto i : view) {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

It could look a little contrived, but I would argue that such a pattern could be an alternative to consider for some real-world cases of range encoding. The point of views::istream in the code above is to get an input_range that is not a forward_range, something we'd want to support in general (files, networks, etc.).
The program above prints "37" on godbolt. Is that what it should do? It could look like that, but that program is in fact ill-formed!
And that is not only some language-lawyer talk, it is in fact very concrete. Consider program 2:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{"\x{01}\x{02}\x{03}\x{04}"};

    auto view = std::views::istream<char>(iss) | std::views::chunk(2) |
                std::views::transform([](auto chunk) {
                    return std::ranges::fold_left(chunk, 0, std::plus{});
                });

    static_assert(
        std::ranges::input_range<decltype(std::views::istream<char>(iss))>);
    static_assert(not std::ranges::forward_range<
                  decltype(std::views::istream<char>(iss))>);

    auto it = view.begin();

    std::cout << *it << *it << '\n';
}

That program prints "30" on godbolt, i.e. the dereferenced value at the start of the view is both 3 and 0!
Such multiple dereferencing is exactly what std::views::cartesian_product will do.
Those programs are ill-formed because std::view::transform's argument is not std::regular_invocable. It is not std::regular_invocable because it changes its own argument, which std::regular_invocable functions are required not to do. The reason why it changes its own argument is that that argument, a chunk, is an input range that is not a forward range, i.e. it cannot be accessed without being consumed.
In practice, upon second invocation for the same top view position, the folding will get an empty range and hence yield zero.
As mentioned in that answer, there is P3138 aka views::cache_last, proposed for standardization, which, added to the pipeline, would avoid multiple evaluations, but as far as I understand, even with that, the programs above would still be formally ill-formed.
I'm assuming relying on ill-formedness is not an option so is there a plan to make the programs above, with views::cache_last somehow added to the pipeline, not ill-formed? Maybe std::views::transform could have a views::cache_last option, which, if true, would make it OK to consume the input, or something similar?

Barry's latest comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067807/3246135 might be answer enough for me. I'm still interested in hearing other opinions, however. Also, this question might be easier to find than the one mentioned above when searching for such topics.

My claim that the invocable modifies its argument is likely to be incorrect, because that argument should be a view passed by value (the modification is a side-effect). In which case, the only requirement the invocable breaks is equality-preservation. As comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067807/3246135 have showed, that is not observable if views::cache_last is used, and hence, no further precaution should be necessary.

I have now accepted Caleth's answer after his patient work of convincing in the comments. More specifically, I am accepting his input_transform. I have also made a journey from thinking that ill-formedness cannot be acceptable, though thinking that maybe it could be, to now again being convinced that it cannot be.

An other thing that you can do to avoid ill-formedness is to remove the transform.
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

auto sum_chunk(auto chunk) {
    return std::ranges::fold_left(chunk, 0, std::plus{});
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{"\x{01}\x{02}\x{03}\x{04}"};

    auto view = std::views::istream<char>(iss) | std::views::chunk(2);

    for (const auto chunk : view) {
        std::cout << sum_chunk(chunk);
    }
}

Or you can implement your own version of views::transform, which only requires invocable rather than regular_invocable and only provides an input_range as it's result.
template <typename F>
struct input_transform : std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure<input_transform<F>>
{
    F f;
 
    template <std::input_range R>
    requires std::invocable<const F&, std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>
    auto operator()(R&& r) -> std::generator<std::invoke_result_v<const F&, std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>> const {
        for (auto && v : std::forward<R>(r)) { 
            co_yield std::invoke(f, std::forward<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>(v));
        }
    }
};


Is there a plan to make the programs above, with views::cache_last somehow added to the pipeline, not ill-formed?

No. The problem isn't that you are applying transform to an input range, but that the range value type is itself an input range. The following has the same problem, and view is a random_access_range. That's why views::transform requires std::regular_invocable.
std::vector<std::istringstream> isss{
    {"\x{01}\x{02}"},
    {"\x{03}\x{04}"}};

auto view = isss | 
            std::views::transform([](auto& iss) {
                return std::views::istream<char>(iss);
            }) |
            std::views::transform([](auto chunk) {
                return std::ranges::fold_left(chunk, 0, std::plus{});
            });



I want to use view as an atom, for further processing, that is what my pattern argument is about. Removing the transform breaks the view. 2) I'd rather learn how to use these constructs correctly than re-implementing poorer variants. 3) Yes, the chunk itself is an input range. That is, at least in intention, what I wrote, and it is my understanding that this is the exact case in which cache_last solves the practical issue. See also latest in https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067807/3246135.


@nilo 1 you are in a corner case, the design had to upset someone, there isn't a way to be maximally general. 2 you can't use std transform 3 cache_last doesn't fix transform when the outer range is forward or better. That's why I said roll your own, because your transform has side effects. Side effects are hard. It isn't a poorer variant. It is a variant applicable to a different situation.

@nilo input_transform is the other choice the design could have taken, where the transform can exhaust the input, because it can only be invoked once per element.

I wrote this question because 1) Although https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067807/3246135 made sense, I was annoyed by the formally broken requirement. 2) It made sense to have a more minimal case of the same issue. Now, I think point 1 is solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067807/3246135 with further comments (argument of non-observability). Point 2 might still be valid, but now I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067807/3246135 works here too.

"cache_last doesn't fix transform when the outer range is forward or better". No, but then no fix is needed. As I see it, for that case, cache_last is a performance improvement. In other words, cache_last does indeed fix the view in the program, for all cases.

@nilo in the case where the inner range is forward, no, but in the case where you have a forward range of input ranges, you can't fix that with cache_last. For your case, cache_last will probably work, but it will be formally ill-formed. It is not a "broken requirement", because it isn't possible to distinguish between equality-preserving functions and non equality-preserving functions, so there has to be a restriction.

"A forward range of input ranges" is out of the scope of this question as, unless I am mistaken, the OP code cannot generate that (see https://godbolt.org/z/1E7neG8rb and https://godbolt.org/z/W44GzvK4E). If "it isn't possible to distinguish between equality-preserving functions and non equality-preserving functions", why would cache_last only "probably" work? What would make it not work?

@nilo it is still formally ill formed. You formally cannot use std::views::transform with a non equality preserving function, even if you only call it once for each element. There is no plan to make that well-formed, because it isn't detectable.

Yes. For the record, Barry in mentioned comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067807/3246135: "@nilo Technically you're still violating the requirements on transform because the callable still isn't a regular invocable. But that's unobservable, since you're effectively regularizing it with cache_last so it's fine". Fine or not, that's really the question here. My first reflex was "it can't be". But isn't Barry in the committee?

Barry is saying that, because it's undetectable, no compiler is going to do something weird with your program. That doesn't stop the program being ill-formed.

I think we all agree that the program is still ill-formed. After all, I have written exactly that in the original post. Barry says it's fine, you seem to be saying it's not, which, again, was also my first reflex. It just seems to me that since there is a  known solution to the technical problem, it's a pity to let every developer confronted with that problem solve it on their own.

@nilo I agree with Barry that you'll have no problems from the compiler. What you might have a problem with is a business rule requiring the program to be well-formed. "a known solution to the technical problem" it's only a solution in your case, and only if you don't care about following unenforceable requirements. In other cases cache_last isn't a solution

What you call "my case" is simply taking an input range, piping it into chunk, piping the result into transform, and actually using the chunk in the transformation, for instance by folding it. Ill-formed, but also technically solvable with the help of cache_last. It it really reasonable to leave the rest to the developers, you think?

@nilo Yes. std::views::transform is a general purpose thing. It applies to all kinds of ranges. cache_last only suppresses the visible problem with a mutating transform when you do a single pass. It would not be safe, in the general case, for transform to be relaxed to std::invocable from std::regular_invocable. Because it isn't detectable, you can't specialise transform to return an input range that caches in the case where it isn't equality preserving. If you cache all the time, you break transform's ability to return references

You are only disqualifying one solution. The OP question is loose and not advocating that solution more than any other. To start with, do you agree that views::chunk(n) | views::transform(f) is basically broken as soon as the input range is only an input_range?

@nilo if the transform doesn't read the inner range, but wraps it up in something else, then no

I had overlooked your input_transform, as a matter of principle, favoring a pure std solution, but realize now that that was unfair. Is it really that easy to write a range adaptor with std::generator and co_yield? I have to test that. Accepting the answer, now, thanks a lot.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
